# Performing a JNDI lookup in a JAXB XmlAdapter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jersey

My project is a Java Enterprise project and consists of three modules:

- Assembly (EAR)

  - EJB (JAR)
  - Web (WAR)

My domain model resides in the EJB. This includes a `Manufacturer` class and a `Model` class. A one-to-many relationship exists between the two. I expose instances of these manufacturers and models through a REST interface that resides in my web project.

Whenever I access one of these manufacturers, the following XML-code is generated:

```
<manufacturer id=1>
    <name>Ford</name>
    <models>
        <model id=1>
            <name>Fiesta</name>
        </model>
        <model id=2>
            <name>Focus</name>
        </model>
    </models>
</manufacturer>
```

However, I want it to be like this:

```
<manufacturer id=1>
    <name>Ford</name>
    <models>
        <model>1</model>
        <model>2</model>
    </models>
</manufacturer>
```

I have achieved the desired effect by writing a specialized `XmlAdapter`, `ModelAdapter` and annotate the field in the `Manufacturer` class with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ModelAdapter.class)`. This adapter resides in my EJB module as well. A problem arises, however, when a `Model` needs to be unmarshalled:

```
private ModelFacade modelFacade;

@Override
public Model unmarshal(Long id) throws Exception {
    return modelFacade.find(id);
}
```

The `ModelFacade`, a stateless session bean, can not be injected into the `XmlAdapter` and the unmarshalling process will therefore always fail.

I have been advised to write a `MessageBodyReader` in order to be able to "manually" instantiate the adapter and pass the facade as an argument but this specialized message body reader would need to be implemented in the web module. I would very much like contain this behaviour in the EJB module for the simple reason that if I ever decide to create, for instance, a desktop application that depends on the EJB, I don't need to deal with the same issue again.

In order to achieve this behaviour, I can perform a JNDI lookup in the constructor of the adapter:

```
public AbstractAdapter(String name) throws NamingException {
    facade = (AbstractFacade<B>) lookup("java:app/MyEJB/" + name);
}

private Object lookup(String name) throws NamingException {
    Context c = new InitialContext();
    return c.lookup(name);
}
```

and this will work perfectly fine, but I am not sure this is the right way to go. Is doing an JNDI lookup from an EJB module a perfectly fine solution or is there a more favourable one?

Comment: Your solution works it's concise and does not involve any hacks. Why are you looking for another solution?

Comment: @Kingo Thanks for your response! I am reticent because it involves embedding the name of my EJB in a static string. What if the module is ever deployed using a different name? Users would need to go in the source to change it. What else is holding me back is that while you say it does not involve hacks, in a CDI environment doing a JNDI lookup does feel like it. How common is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify a parameter of type `java.io.InputStream` on your JAX-RS method (which is on the session bean).  Then you could unmarshal that `InputStream` leveraging JAXB.  This would give you the opportunity to configure the `javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller` with the appropriate `XmlAdapter`.

**For More Information**

- https://wink.apache.org/documentation/1.0/html/JAX-RS%20Request%20and%20Response%20Entities.html

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware it was possible to replace the JAXBElement with the actual InputStream. This solves it quite elegantly.